# force doxygen to pick one from versioned files

Tags: file, filter, version, doxygen

Just started using doxygen today. How would you go about this.

Given following dir structure

```
-rootDir
    -dirA
        -dirAFile_ver01
        -dirAFile_ver02
        -dirAFile_ver03
        -dirAFile_ver04
    -dirB
        -dirBFile_ver01
        -dirBFile_ver02
        -dirBFile_ver03
    -dirC
        -dirCFile_ver01
        -dirCFile_ver02
```

My expectations from doxygen are to take only last version of file from single dir e.g. `dirAFile_ver04 from dirA`, `dirBFile_ver03 from dirB` etc. I've read about **FILE_VERSION_FILTER** tag, but I'm not able to make it work. Using CMD command for listing last file (sort by name)
`FILE_VERSION_FILTER = FOR /f %i IN ('dir /o:n /b') DO (set LAST_VER=%i echo %LAST_VER%)`

Also would it be possible if all those files would lie in single directory?

```
-rootDir
    -dirAFile_ver01
    -dirAFile_ver02
    -dirAFile_ver03
    -dirAFile_ver04
    -dirBFile_ver01
    -dirBFile_ver02
    -dirBFile_ver03
    -dirCFile_ver01
    -dirCFile_ver02
    -justFile_0.0.1
    -justFile_0.0.2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The  FILE_VERSION_FILTER (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_file_version_filter) is definitely not suitable for the purpose you have. Having different versions of a file in a directory is something that is not done, it is a task of a version control system (how do you handle this during builds?).

The  FILE_VERSION_FILTER gets from a version control system or any other command you put there some information and outputs it to standard output and uses it in some output (for headers).

Maybe you can accomplish something with INPUT_FILTER (check the filename in your script to see if it is the last one and if so output it, otherwise output nothing. I didn't test anything here). Another possibility might be with FILTER_PATTERNS but I doubt this as it uses a regular expression and I'm not aware of any regular expression that can do this.